# How to store and load a Python dictionary with HDF5

Tags: python, dictionary, hdf5, h5py

I'm having issues loading (I think storing is working – a file is being created and contains data) a dictionary (string key and array/list value) from a HDF5 file. I'm receiving the following error:

> ValueError: malformed node or string: < HDF5 dataset "dataset_1": shape (), type "|O" >

My code is:

```py
import h5py

def store_table(self, filename):
    table = dict()
    table['test'] = list(np.zeros(7,dtype=int))

    with h5py.File(filename, "w") as file:
        file.create_dataset('dataset_1', data=str(table))
        file.close()


def load_table(self, filename):
    file = h5py.File(filename, "r")
    data = file.get('dataset_1')
    print(ast.literal_eval(data))
```

I've read online using the **ast** method **literal_eval** should work but it doesn't appear to help... How do I 'unpack' the HDF5 so it's a dictionary again?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered creating attributes? Each attribute name==key name and attribute value==key value. That way you avoid the problem handling different value datatypes. (For example one value is a string, one is a integer, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, this should work:

```
import numpy as np
import ast
import h5py


def store_table(filename):
    table = dict()
    table['test'] = list(np.zeros(7,dtype=int))

    with h5py.File(filename, "w") as file:
        file.create_dataset('dataset_1', data=str(table))


def load_table(filename):
    file = h5py.File(filename, "r")
    data = file.get('dataset_1')[...].tolist()
    file.close();
    return ast.literal_eval(data)

filename = "file.h5"
store_table(filename)
data = load_table(filename)
print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want to store a dictionary (string key and array/list value).

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to to that, but I updated my code accordingly. In general you will store the key and the value in different datasets (in the same file).

Comment: Amazing, that works! I wasn't aware the key and values should be stored separately – why is that? And how would I combine them again when retrieving the dictionary? Thank you!

Comment: Great! Note that the key in your example is the name of the dataset and not the key of the dictionary. This means that to store a dictionary you could have two datasets, lets call the first "key" and the second "value" such that the ith element of the "key" dataset and the ith element of the "value" dataset are a valid key/value pair in the original dictionary.

Comment: I'm planning for this dictionary to contain many thousands of items; would it still be wise to store them separately?  "Note that the key in your example" – to which key are you referring, 'test' or 'dataset_1'? Would I use a loop to store each of the key/values values in their respective datasets?

Comment: What i'm referring as key is 'test' and 'key' is the name of a dataset ('dataset_1' in your example). It will be wise to store them separately and the easiest way to do it is by constructing two Numpy arrays: one of dictionary keys and the other of dictionary values.

Comment: Thank you. To combine them (the two np.arrays – keys_arr and values_arr) again into a single dictionary, I presume I would need to loop through them, placing into a dictionary? Or, is the a more succinct Python way of doing it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211716/discussion-between-mrob-and-mason7663).

Comment: @MROB You forgot to close the file in the second function and you close it twice in the first one!

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me what you really want to accomplish. (I suspect your dictionaries have more than seven zeros. Otherwise, HDF5 is overkill to store your data.) If you have a lot of very large dictionaries, it would be better to covert the data to a NumPy array then either 1) create and load the dataset with `data=` or 2) create the dataset with an appropriate `dtype` then populate. You can create datasets with mixed datatypes, which is not addressed in the previous solution. If those situations don't apply, you might want to save the dictionary as attributes. Attributes can be associated to a group, a dataset, or the file object itself. Which is best depends on your requirements.

I wrote a short example to show how to load dictionary key/value pairs as attribute names/value pairs tagged to a group. For this example, I assumed the dictionary has a name key with the group name for association. The process is almost identical for a dataset or file object (just change the object reference).

```
import h5py

def load_dict_to_attr(h5f, thisdict) :

   if 'name' not in thisdict:
       print('Dictionary missing name key. Skipping function.')
       return

   dname = thisdict.get('name') 
   if dname in h5f:
       print('Group:' + dname + ' exists. Skipping function.')
       return
   else: 
       grp = h5f.create_group(dname)

       for key, val in thisdict.items():
           grp.attrs[key] = val

###########################################

def get_grp_attrs(name, node) :

    grp_dict = {}
    for k in node.attrs.keys():
        grp_dict[k]= node.attrs[k]

    print (grp_dict)

###########################################

car1 = dict( name='my_car', brand='Ford', model='Mustang', year=1964,
             engine='V6',  disp=260,  units='cu.in' )
car2 = dict( name='your_car', brand='Chevy', model='Camaro', year=1969,
             engine='I6',  disp=250,  units='cu.in' )
car3 = dict( name='dads_car', brand='Mercedes', model='350SL', year=1972,
             engine='V8',  disp=4520, units='cc' )
car4 = dict( name='moms_car', brand='Plymouth', model='Voyager', year=1989,
             engine='V6',  disp=289,  units='cu.in' )

a_truck = dict(             brand='Dodge', model='RAM', year=1984,
               engine='V8', disp=359, units='cu.in' )

garage = dict(my_car=car1, 
              your_car=car2,
              dads_car=car3,
              moms_car=car4,
              a_truck=a_truck )

with h5py.File('SO_61226773.h5','w') as h5w:

    for car in garage:
        print ('\nLoading dictionary:', car)
        load_dict_to_attr(h5w, garage.get(car))

with h5py.File('SO_61226773.h5','r') as h5r:

    print ('\nReading dictionaries from Group attributes:')
    h5r.visititems (get_grp_attrs)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool, [`hdfdict`](https://pypi.org/project/hdfdict/) that may help for your case.

```py
import h5py
import hdfdict

garage = dict(...)  # Taken from your code, here omitted

# Write to hdf file

with h5py.File('test.h5', 'w') as f:
    hdfdict.dump(garage, f.require_group('garage'))
    print('###############################')
    print('Dumped file: ')
    print(f.visit(lambda name: print(name)))

# Load in memory
with h5py.File('test.h5', 'r') as f:
    loaded_garage = hdfdict.load(f.require_group('garage'), False)
    print('###############################')
    print(loaded_garage)
```

The result:

```
###############################
Dumped file: 
garage
garage/a_truck
garage/a_truck/brand
garage/a_truck/disp
garage/a_truck/engine
garage/a_truck/model
garage/a_truck/units
garage/a_truck/year
garage/dads_car
garage/dads_car/brand
garage/dads_car/disp
garage/dads_car/engine
garage/dads_car/model
garage/dads_car/name
garage/dads_car/units
garage/dads_car/year
garage/moms_car
garage/moms_car/brand
garage/moms_car/disp
garage/moms_car/engine
garage/moms_car/model
garage/moms_car/name
garage/moms_car/units
garage/moms_car/year
garage/my_car
garage/my_car/brand
garage/my_car/disp
garage/my_car/engine
garage/my_car/model
garage/my_car/name
garage/my_car/units
garage/my_car/year
garage/your_car
garage/your_car/brand
garage/your_car/disp
garage/your_car/engine
garage/your_car/model
garage/your_car/name
garage/your_car/units
garage/your_car/year
None
###############################
{'a_truck': {'brand': b'Dodge', 'disp': 359, 'engine': b'V8', 'model': b'RAM', 'units': b'cu.in', 'year': 1984}, 'dads_car': {'brand': b'Mercedes', 'disp': 4520, 'engine': b'V8', 'model': b'350SL', 'name': b'dads_car', 'units': b'cc', 'year': 1972}, 'moms_car': {'brand': b'Plymouth', 'disp': 289, 'engine': b'V6', 'model': b'Voyager', 'name': b'moms_car', 'units': b'cu.in', 'year': 1989}, 'my_car': {'brand': b'Ford', 'disp': 260, 'engine': b'V6', 'model': b'Mustang', 'name': b'my_car', 'units': b'cu.in', 'year': 1964}, 'your_car': {'brand': b'Chevy', 'disp': 250, 'engine': b'I6', 'model': b'Camaro', 'name': b'your_car', 'units': b'cu.in', 'year': 1969}}
```

Note: in my case, using `dict(hdfdict.load(f.require_group('garage'))` would *unlazy* only top-level elements, while using the `lazy=False` attribute works in loading everything into memory
Note2: Strings are saved and loaded as bytes. You have to deal with it

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution is just to convert them to ascii and then store this binary data.

```
import h5py
import json
import itertools
#generate a test dictionary
testDict={
    "one":1,
    "two":2,
    "three":3,
    "otherStuff":[{"A":"A"}]
}

testFile=h5py.File("test.h5","w")
#create a test data set containing the binary representation of my dictionary data
testFile.create_dataset(name="dictionary",shape=(len([i.encode("ascii","ignore") for i in json.dumps(testDict)]),1),dtype="S10",data=[i.encode("ascii","ignore") for i in json.dumps(testDict)])


testFile.close()

testFile=h5py.File("test.h5","r")
#load the test data back
dictionary=testFile["dictionary"][:].tolist()
dictionary=list(itertools.chain(*dictionary))
dictionary=json.loads(b''.join(dictionary))
```

The two key parts are:

```
testFile.create_dataset(name="dictionary",shape=(len([i.encode("ascii","ignore") for i in json.dumps(testDict)]),1),dtype="S10",data=[i.encode("ascii","ignore") for i in json.dumps(testDict)])
```

Where

```
data=[i.encode("ascii","ignore") for i in json.dumps(testDict)])
```

Converts the dictionary to a list of ascii charecters (The string shape may also be calculated from this)

Decoding back from the hdf5 container is a little simpler:

```
dictionary=testFile["dictionary"][:].tolist()
dictionary=list(itertools.chain(*dictionary))
dictionary=json.loads(b''.join(dictionary))
```

All that this is doing is loading the string from the hdf5 container and converting it to a list of bytes. Then I coerce this into a bytes object which I can convert back to a dictionary with json.loads

If you are ok with the extra library usage (json, ittertools) I think this offers a somewhat more pythonic solution (which in my case wasnt a problem since I was using them anyway).